# Sent email to entity reference node email field on checkout

Tags: entities

I have a commerce store and my client don't want a regler checkout. On the checkout a email must be sent to a marketer of the users choice.

For this I have setup a content type with all the users contact details in for the user to find but when a user order some products the order must be sent to the marketer to prosses.

I have add a entity ref. Field in the billing information.

But I can't get the rules to pickup the email field in the entity reference.

What is the correct settings for this?

Answer (score 0):

The first action for your rule should be "Fetch entity by id." Specify the entity type for the billing information for the entity type. In the Identifier field, use the Data Selector to find the token for the id of that entity type. Now create a second action, "Send mail." The information from the entity you specified in the first action will now be available to you for the Send mail action.

Comment: i cant see my token in Data Selector to find the token for the id of that entity type its not showing up

Comment: What is the event that you're using to trigger this rule?

Comment: Completing the checkout process

Comment: In your original post, you say that "a email must be sent to a marketer of the users choice." When does the user make that choice? Does it depend on the product the user buys? You need to include the entity in a meaningful way at some point in the process so that the entity's fields will be available in the Data Selector.